# How to add records to custom object in salesforce?

Tags: custom-object, object

I have created custom object named as `"Vacation Package"` and added custom `picklist` value called `Difficulty` and specify two values: `Easy` and `Hard`. Now I want to insert the following four records. How Can I insert that ?

[image]

Comment: Where do those records reside? Or you want to create them from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *a lot* of ways to get data in to Salesforce. The easiest way to import multiple records is arguably the [Import Wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_import_wizard.htm&language=en&type=0). Create a CSV file with the data to import, then go to Setup > Data Management > Data Import Wizard, and map the fields. For this small amount of data, you could also just go to the tab (Setup > Create > Tabs if you haven't already created a tab), and create the four records manually.

To create a CSV file, you can open Microsoft Excel, Open Office, or another spreadsheet software, populate the cells, and save as a CSV, or you can create one manually using a plain text editor (Notepad is good, Wordpad and Word is bad), and create it by hand. The file would look like this:

```
Name,Difficulty
Base-Two Jumping,Hard
Deep-Sea Beta Fishing,Easy
Swim with Sharks,Hard
Zipline,Easy
```

The Data Import Wizard itself simply asks you for the object you want to import to, the file to import, and then asks you to map the fields, labelled by the first row in the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Data Wizard or data loader to create bulk records.
If you want to create a new records for a custom object in Salesforce

You should create tabs to see the 'objects' in App Launcher.

Go to Setup > Tabs > Custom Object Tabs > New

Add the Custom Object to Tabs and now you would be to search for the custom object in the App Launcher, and you can create records.